# Central limit theorem to estimate the probability of number of votes

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

In a given country A and B are candidates in the current elections. It is known that 60% vote for A and 40% vote for B. A poller polls 10,000 voters in the country. Use the central limit theorem to estimate the probability of less than 6100 of the people questioned for the poll would vote for candiate A.

I have several issues:

1. "60% vote A, 40% vote B" - Does that mean that if $X_i$ is a Bernoulli RV representing a vote by one of the people questioned, $X_i$ ~ $Ber(\frac{3}{5})$? Why?
2. We defined the central limit theorem as follows: If $X_i$ are RVs with expectation $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$, then
   $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_1+\dots+x_n - n\mu}{\sqrt{n}\sigma} = Z$ where  $Z$ ~ $N(0,1)$. I think I'm then supposed to use the CDF of $Z$ to estimate $X$ - but I'm not really estimating $X$ but $Z$, no?

I know this is might be pretty simple but I'm new to this subject, hopefully this isn't a bad question.
Thank you!

Comment: To your first question:  Essentially, yes.  To solve the problem you assume that each person polled is a uniformly random draw from the population, hence will be a vote for $A$ with probability $\frac 35$.  Of course, this is a real problem with actual polls...it's hard to eliminate bias from the selection process.  But here, you have to assume that this is a truly unbiased selection.

Comment: To your second question:  Informally, the selection ought to converge to a normal distribution.  Just work out the mean and variance of that limiting distribution and use that to do the computation.  You ought to use a continuity correction in principle, but with numbers this large it shouldn't really matter much.

Comment: I see! So we don't really use the limit since the numbers here are big enough to get an estimate. Right?

Comment: You are using the limit.  The CLT tells you that the discrete distribution produced by sampling approaches the associated normal.  this is highly non-trivial!  For small samples the distribution you get won't look normal at all.  But for $10000$ people you're good.